# PHP shell_exec cp -r

Tags: php, linux, shellexecute, shell-exec

The following PHP code creates a folder called "example.com" inside the "website.com" folder.

```
$src = "/home/www/example.com/";

$dest = "/home/www/website.com/";

shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");
```

How to prevent it from creating a new folder inside the destination folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `*`:

```
$src = "/home/www/example.com/*";
$dest = "/home/www/website.com/";
shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");
```

Comment: Cant believe i could miss that.. Thx so much!